# Sorting linked list (ADT Priority Que)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, priority-queue, abstract-data-type

I am implementing Priority QUE as a doubly linked list.
My structs:

```
typedef int kintyr;

typedef struct qElem {
    struct qElem *prv;          
    kintyr *dat;                    
    int *priority;
}qElem;


typedef struct que {
    qElem *fr,*bk;              
    int cnt;                    
}que;
```

And this is my functions to create empty PQ, and to insert elements:

```
que *qNew()
{
    que *q = malloc(sizeof(*q));

if (q==NULL)
    return NULL;

q->fr = NULL;
q->bk = NULL;
q->cnt = 0;


qFault = 0;
return q;
}

que *qEnq(que *q, kintyr *x, int *prrt)
{
    que *zn=q;
    qFault = 0;
    if (q == NULL)
    {
        qFault = 1;
        return q;
    }
    if (qCHKf(q) == 1)
    {
        qFault = 3;
        return q;
    }
    qElem *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
    new->prv = NULL;
    new->dat = x;
    new->priority=prrt;

    if (q->fr == NULL || q->fr->priority>prrt  ) 
    {
        new->prv=q->fr;
        q->fr = new;

    }
    else
    {
        que *tempas=q;
        while(tempas->fr->prv!=NULL && tempas->fr->priority<=prrt)
            tempas=tempas->fr;

        new->prv=tempas->fr;
        tempas->fr=new;
    } 
        q->cnt++;
        return q;

}
```

It works good if I add for example elements with priority 7, then 4, then 5.

```
4->5->7
```

But if I add element with priority 7, then 6, then 8. It appears:

```
6->8->7
```

Do you have any ideas how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Replace q->fr with q. So change the code as below.

```
    if (q == NULL || q->priority>prrt  ) 
    {
        new->prv=q;
        q = new;

    }
```